# Ionic served as web app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an Ionic app which I currently serve as a web app by doing `ionic serve`

I have few questions about it:

1. By default in the served web app, it takes the iOS layout, can it be changed to the android layout instead? ***How?***
2. In the android version of y ionic app when I do `ionic serve --lab`, some of the bottom part of the content is somehow cut off (I can not scroll till the end), however it looks perfect in iOS version. ***Why does this happen and how can I fix it?***
3. When I try to make an APK out of it as mentioned in the following link  http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html , I get a blank app on my android device. ***What could be the reason?***

Comment: I can only help you with the first one: In your app's [config](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/Config/), declare `mode: 'md'`

Answer (score 0):

1. ionic serve --platform android
2. Are you taking in account that iOS scroll "stretches"? I mean, even when the scroll is all way down, you still can pull the content up. Maybe your content is **indeed hidden** (specially if you are using a footer bar. Actually, if you are using a footer bar, try to add a margin-bottom for your content equal your footer bar height.).
3. Have you checked if this happens when you run **ionic run android**? If this command works, try to run **cordova prepare android** before following the publishing procedure. If the command does not work, open **chrome://inspect** on your computer's chrome browser (with the device connected to your computer and running your app) and debug it to check if your code is being packed with the apk and/or the app is yielding some error messages.